# Resources to build SNMP support for my device?

Tags: snmp, agent, mib, net-snmp

Can any one recommend resources for adding SNMP support for my device? my understanding the steps I need to do are as follow:

- Create a MIB file that define what values your MIB will support
- Use code generator to convert it to C module
- Use generated code to fetch real values
- Convert the module to an agentx sub agent, so you can integrate your MIB a separate process that could work with any snmp agent that support agentx protocol.

Are my assumption correct, any suggestions or corrections, I am specially looking for resources that help me, books, courses, online, etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your questions would be answered differently depending on which toolkit you go with.  However, if you run with the common Net-SNMP one (free as in beer) then you should probably start with the tutorials on that site that walks you through much of what you're asking.

http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials

However, it doesn't discuss how to write a MIB.  For that the best book on the subject is "Understanding SNMP MIBs".